# Unitary matrices and preservation of inner product - necessary and sufficient?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two vector functions, $\vec{a}(z):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$, and $\vec{b}(z):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$. Suppose also that the following equation holds:

(1) $$\langle\vec{a}(x),\vec{a}(y)\rangle=\langle\vec{b}(x),\vec{b}(y)\rangle,\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb{R},$$

where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ indicates the Hermitian inner product. Clearly it is sufficient that there exists a unitary matrix $\mathbf{U}$ which is independent of $z$ such that

(2) $$\vec{a}(z)=\mathbf{U}\vec{b}(z), \forall z \in \mathbb{R}.$$ In other words, $(2)\Rightarrow(1)$. Is this condition also necessary? That is, $$(1)\overset{?}{\Rightarrow}(2).$$

If not, can we find a counter-example?

---

Indeed, for $n=1$ this would mean $$a(x)a^\ast(y)=b(x)b^\ast(y),\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow a(z)=e^{i\phi}b(z),\phi\in\mathbb{R}.$$ This case can be easily shown: We have $$\frac{a^\ast(y)}{b^\ast(y)}a(x)=b(x),\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\\ \Rightarrow \frac{a^\ast(y)}{b^\ast(y)}=k\in\mathbb{C} \\
\Rightarrow a(x)a^\ast(y)=|k|^2a(x)a^\ast(y)\\
\Rightarrow k=e^{i\phi}\\ \Rightarrow a(z)=e^{i\phi}b(z)$$

Comment: I don't think so since taking enough points $x_i$, $y_i$ and values $a(x_i)$ and $b(x_i)$ with the right values will determine eventually enough equation as to exceed the nuber of coefficients of the matrix.

Comment: @Nimda. Can you find a counter-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that, for every $x,y$: $(a(x),a(y))=(b(x),b(y))$ for the standard hermitian product and we construct a unitary matrix $U$ s.t. $a=Ub$.

Assume that $span(im(a))=\mathbb{C}^n$ ; let $(x_i)_{i\leq n}$ s.t. $(a(x_i))_i$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Since $(a(x_i),a(x_j))=(b(x_i),b(x_j))$, $(b(x_i))_i$ is also a basis and there is a unitary matrix $U$ s.t., for every $i\leq n$, $a(x_i)=Ub(x_i)$.

Thus, for every $i$, $(a(x),a(x_i))=(b(x),b(x_i))=(a(x),Ub(x_i))$, that is $(b(x),b(x_i))=(U^{-1}a(x),b(x_i))$. Finally $U^{-1}a(x)=b(x)$, that is $a=Ub$.

EDIT: if $E=span(im(a))$ is not $\mathbb{C}^n$, then we show, in the same way that there is $V$, unitary on $E$ s.t. $a=Vb$. There is $U$ unitary on $\mathbb{C}^n$ s.t. $U_{|E}=V$.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. Can you please explain what $im(a)$ means? Also, I agree that it can be done without stars if you use the hermitian inner product and perhaps the arrows are unnecessary but I wouldn't say dismal. Please feel free to edit the question to make it conform with more conventional notation and/or to make it more general.

Comment: @ SDiv , Ok "unclear" would be better. $im(a)$ denotes the image of the function $a$. I add a edit for the case when $span(im(a))$ is not $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Thanks again for the edit, I was going to ask about that case. If you don't mind, could you quickly let me know where I am going wrong in the notation so that I don't make these mistakes again?

Comment: @ Sdiv , there are no mistakes, only awkwards s.t. 1. for complex vectors, you use the euclidean product. 2. for almost all mathematicians, the star notation denotes the conjugate transpose.

Comment: I have edited the question - many of these comments are now irrelevant.